# Is AFCI required for detached workshop subpanel?

Tags: subpanel, nec, afci, workshop

As I read the 2014 NEC 210.12 AFCI protection is only required for a "dwelling unit", which would not include a detached workshop.  Is that interpretation correct?

Comment: The code is the minimum standard required. Point is do you want to minimize your safety or maximize it? What epitaph on your headstone? “I went with the minimum - look where I am now” :)

Comment: Well, I guess it's far safer to not run electricity to the shop at all.  No risk of electrocution, greatly reduced risk of fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret the 2014 code requirement the same way. However the real question is how does the AHJ in you area interpret the code. You might check with him about what they require before making a decision.

Comment: State law where I live specifically expands dwelling unit to "related structures".

Comment: I'm in Virginia.  The electrician at the code office said that VA interprets "dwelling" as bedrooms...but he was not clear in the e-mail so I thought I'd ask here.  I've also send a followup e-mail, but it is the weekend.  Thanks for the feedback.